# best practice for mvc razor view layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am looking for best practices for design razor view with MVC.

which would be better option:
 HtmlHelper extension methods

```
    @Html.TextBox("txtName")
```

or
 write the html directly

```
    <input type"text" id="txtName" name="txtName" />
```

I found 2 diferent links. 
The first one http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aspnetue/archive/2010/09/17/second_2d00_post.aspx says **DO use HTMLHelper extension methods.**
and the second one http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2009/10/27/12-asp.net-mvc-best-practices.aspx says **10 – Write HTML each time you can**

so i am a little cofused

Comment: What ever you feel more comfortable with. Just pick one design and be consistent throughout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even the name `HtmlHelper` should already give you a hint whether you should use it or not. Do you want help? If not, just write html from the scratch. It does not really matter how the html was generated: from the scratch or using html helper. What matter is that it was generated with correct names of the inputs so that model binder can bind these inputs to the model.

For example, suppose you have the following Model that will be passed to the view and that will be received on the POST:

```cs
public class SomeModel
{
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

In order to make sure that your inputs will be binded to the model  you need three inputs on your page:

```html
<input type="hidden" id="whatever" name="Customer.Id" /> 
<input type="text" id="whatever" name="Customer.FirstName" />
<input type="text" id="whatever" name="Customer.LastName" />
```

Having this html markup will assure proper model minding. However, you can achieve this markup by using HtmlHelpers, which is a lot easier:

```cs
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Customer.Id)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Customer.FirstName)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Customer.LastName)
```

This will not only give you proper `name` attributes on every input, but also assign `id` attributes accordingly so you don't have to do that all by your self.

---

It appears that the author from the second article suggests to never use HtmlHelpers for two reasons:

1. the learning purposes: I assume by saying "web developers have to be
   comfortable writing HTML" he means that developer should know
   exactly what html markup is required for proper model binding.
2. the fear of black box: It seem that author is afraid that improper html
       markup will be generated by using HtmlHelpers or he just does not
       know what html will be generated.

I disagree with his phrase: "HtmlHelpers whose only reason of living is hiding the HTML away". I'd rather say "HtmlHelpers whose only reason of living is helping writing Html markup"

---

**Summary:**
HtmlHelpers **help** you write proper html markup, which is why I suggest you using it.

Comment: but what happend if i want a web developer modify de layout for me? with only razor markup how he/she could see the disegn in a web broser?

Comment: The layout has nothing to do with the forms. HtmlHelpers are used to create html markup for inputs mostly, not the layout. You seem to be a bit confused on what HtmlHelpers actually achieve. Perhaps, if you modified your question with a specific example of the problem that you are trying to solve, I'd be able to guide you better.

Comment: Charly - _but what happend if i want a web developer modify de layout for me?_. Your web developer should understand web development. Did you mean a front-end designer? In which case, get them to design a form with the presentation layer properly abstracted (e.g. _please use classes and not IDs or names when creating the CSS for this form_). It is fairly straight forward to add classes to MVC HtmlHelpers - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465133/actionlink-with-multiple-classes-in-asp-net-mvc3. Alternately, provide them with the form and wait for them to ask questions or look it up.

Comment: @AaronNewton i mean if a web developer open the layout in dreamweaver for example, it shows the HtmlHelper markup intead of the proper html markup

Comment: a **web developer** should not open his work in Dreamweaver. However, that's a side note. Indeed there will be HtmlHelper markup. The developer, who's working on the project should be able to understand it and foresee what html markup will be outputted.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using `Razor`, I would make the most of what it has to offer, and the `HtmlHelper` extensions allow you to write html quicker and easier in a lot of places.

There may be times when you have to use Html instead, where you might want to include tags in an anchor and cannot use `@Html.ActionLink`, for example.

But where you can achieve the same result with either approach, I'd recommend you go with `Razor`.

Comment: I agree. I'd like to add that entering the HTML code is absolute - you will not be able to modify it aside from editing the HTML markup directly, and you will need to change the markup for every instance (more or less what Tyler just said). A HtmlHelper on the other hand can be custom defined, and used to consistently add markup in many places http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs. You can also override the behaviour - http://forums.asp.net/t/1574560.aspx/1

Answer (score 0):

Html helpers are not cosmetic code snippets that just save time. Consider choosing the appropriate editor based on model property types, and - what is also very important - they help in client validation, provided you include jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js and jquery.validate.js.
 
The last cannot be achieved by simply writing HTML.
 
From what I said it can be easily derived that Html helpers "know" about the model, while plain markup does not.
At the end it is up to you to decide what to use, but knowing more about Html helpers is better when making a decision.